# Why won't my last column show?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to duplicate a web forum and am running into a problem with the columns. For some reason I can't get the last column to show up and have no idea why this is happening. What I am trying to duplicate is:

[image]

My code so far:

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="col1">
    <h2><u> Lab 04 </u></h2>
    <p class= "fontClass">
      Papa's 
      <br />
      Pizza
    </p>
    <hr>
    <p class= "fontClass">
      416 or 905
      <br />
      222-2626
    </p>
    <hr />
    <table class='price'>
      <tr>
        <td class='pricetd'>Small</td>
        <td class='pricetd'>$11.55</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='pricetd'>Medium</td>
        <td class='pricetd'>$15.25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='pricetd'>Large</td>
        <td class='pricetd'>$22.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='pricetd'>X-Large</td>
        <td class='pricetd'>$25.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='pricetd'>Toppings</td>
        <td class='pricetd'>$1.79 Each</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='pricetd'>Plus 13% HST</td>
        <td class='pricetd'>Free Delivery</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <p>your price</p>
    <input class='total' type='text' name='price' id='price' readonly='readonly' maxlength='8' />
    <p>
      <input type="submit"  class="button" value="PLACE YOUR ORDER" />
      <input type="reset"  value="    Clear   " />  
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="col2">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Personal Information</legend>
      <p>
        Name       
        <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" maxlength="15">
        <br>
        Account No.
        <input type="text" name="client" id="client" maxlength="12">
        <br>
        Phone No.  
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" maxlength="12">
        <br>
        Date of Birth
        <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" maxlength="7">
      </p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Pizza size and Crust</legend>
      <select id="pizzaSize" name="pizzaSize" size="2">
        <option value="Select Pizza Size">Select Pizza Size</option>
        <option value="S">Small</option>
        <option value="M">Medium</option>
        <option value="L">Large</option>
        <option value="X">X-Large</option>
      </select>
      <select id="pizzaCrust" name="pizzaCrust" size="2">
        <option value="regular">Regular Crust</option>
        <option value="thin">Thin Crust</option>
        <option value="thick">Thick Crust</option>
        <option value="wheat">Whole Wheat Crust</option>
      </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Cheeses</legend>
      <p>
        <input type="radio" name="cheese" id="c01" value="Mozzarella" />Mozzarella
        <input type="radio" name="cheese" id="c02" value="Reduced Fat" />Reduced Fat
        <input type="radio" name="cheese" id="c03" value="Feta" />Feta
      </p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Sauces</legend>
      <p>
        <input type="radio" name="sauce" id="s01" value="Pizza  Sauce" />Pizza Sauce
        <input type="radio" name="sauce" id="s02" value="BBQ Sauce" />BBQ Sauce
        <input type="radio" name="sauce" id="s03" value="Garlic Sauce" />Garlic Sauce
      </p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Special instructions</legend>
      <textarea name="note" id="note" maxlength="150"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div id="col3">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Choose toppings - $1.79 each</legend>
      <div id="col3A">
        <label for="t01"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t01" value="Anchovies">Anchovies</label>
        <label for="t02"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t02" value="Bacon">Bacon</label>
        <label for="t03"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t03" value="Ham">Ham</label>
        <label for="t04"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t04" value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni</label>
        <label for="t05"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t05" value="Salami">Salami</label>
        <label for="t06"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t06" value="Sausage">Sausage</label>
      </div>
      <div id="col3B">
        <label for="t07"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t07" value="Broccoli">Broccoli</label>
        <label for="t08"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t08" value="Green Olives">Green Olives</label>
        <label for="t09"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t09" value="Green Peppers">Green Peppers</label>
        <label for="t010"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t10" value="Mushrooms">Mushrooms</label>
        <label for="t011"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t11" value="Red Onions">Red Onions</label>
        <label for="t012"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t12" value="Roasted Garlic">Roasted Garlic</label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <div id="special">
        <img src="papas.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the 3rd post you've made about this question/problem. We've told you that you are using tables incorrectly -- they should not be used for layout. And, I even provided you with a solution to create the columns/footer that your screen shot requires.

Comment: I used your suggestion, and it seems to work fine.... I just don't understand why the last column isn't showing. I thought an updated question with the new code was in order. My apologies.

Comment: Everything seems fine except for this last (3rd) column not showing up

Comment: But, you are not using my suggestion because you are still using the tables. You must understand that designing a web page isn't about coding until the page "looks good". The use of the various HTML elements is decided based on the semantic meaning those elements provide. As you are finding, tables are just making things more difficult for you. Just place your fieldsets inside the div elements from my last answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just started learning HTML about a month ago. Would you be able to provide an example of what you're suggesting just to make it a little more clear to me? would be greatly appreciated. And i thank you for the help thus far

Comment: I took out all the table elements, but the 3rd column still seems not to display

Comment: I'm thinking it's being pushed off the page for some reason

Answer (score 0):

This solution simply puts your fieldset content into the div structure that I showed in my earlier answer. Of course, you need to add the rest of your content, but it shows how to get the column layout without using tables. There is also CSS that is required to make this work, but this is how this type of thing is done.

```css
#col1, #col2, #col3 {
      float: left;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #col1 {
      width: 20%;
    }

    #col2, #col3 {
      width: 40%;
    }

    #col3A, #col3B {display:table-cell; width:50%;}

    #footer {
      clear: both;
      background: #000;
      color: #fff;
    }

#col3A > label, #col3B > label {display:block;}

 fieldset {border: 3px dashed red; }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="col1">
      Column One Data Here
    </div>

    <div id="col2">

      <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal Information</legend>
        <p>
          Name       
            <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" maxlength="15">
          <br>
          Account No.
            <input type="text" name="client" id="client" maxlength="12">
          <br>
          Phone No.  
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" maxlength="12">
          <br>
          Date of Birth
            <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" maxlength="7">
        </p>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>
        <legend>Pizza size and Crust</legend>
        <select id="pizzaSize" name="pizzaSize" size="2">
          <option value="Select Pizza Size">Select Pizza Size</option>
          <option value="S">Small</option>
          <option value="M">Medium</option>
          <option value="L">Large</option>
          <option value="X">X-Large</option>
        </select>
        <select id="pizzaCrust" name="pizzaCrust" size="2">
          <option value="regular">Regular Crust</option>
          <option value="thin">Thin Crust</option>
          <option value="thick">Thick Crust</option>
          <option value="wheat">Whole Wheat Crust</option>
        </select>
      </fieldset>
      
            <fieldset>
        <legend>Cheeses</legend>
        <p>
          <input type="radio" name="cheese" id="c01" value="Mozzarella" />Mozzarella
          <input type="radio" name="cheese" id="c02" value="Reduced Fat" />Reduced Fat
          <input type="radio" name="cheese" id="c03" value="Feta" />Feta
        </p>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>
        <legend>Sauces</legend>
        <p>
          <input type="radio" name="sauce" id="s01" value="Pizza  Sauce" />Pizza Sauce
          <input type="radio" name="sauce" id="s02" value="BBQ Sauce" />BBQ Sauce
          <input type="radio" name="sauce" id="s03" value="Garlic Sauce" />Garlic Sauce
        </p>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>
        <legend>Special instructions</legend>
        <textarea name="note" id="note" maxlength="150"></textarea>
      </fieldset>

    </div>
  
    <div id="col3">

     <fieldset>
     <legend>Choose toppings - $1.79 each</legend>
      <div id="col3A">
          <label for="t01"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t01" value="Anchovies">Anchovies</label>
          <label for="t02"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t02" value="Bacon">Bacon</label>
          <label for="t03"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t03" value="Ham">Ham</label>
          <label for="t04"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t04" value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni</label>
          <label for="t05"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t05" value="Salami">Salami</label>
          <label for="t06"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t06" value="Sausage">Sausage</label>
      </div>
      <div id="col3B">
          <label for="t07"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t07" value="Broccoli">Broccoli</label>
          <label for="t08"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t08" value="Green Olives">Green Olives</label>
          <label for="t09"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t09" value="Green Peppers">Green Peppers</label>
          <label for="t010"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t10" value="Mushrooms">Mushrooms</label>
          <label for="t011"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t11" value="Red Onions">Red Onions</label>
          <label for="t012"><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t12" value="Roasted Garlic">Roasted Garlic</label>
      </div>

      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Ahhh ok thank you. And if i wanted to apply CSS to say the individual borders surrounding the cells (ie. Pizza size and Crust cell) what would I refer to to make that happen? Using tables, i know how it would be done, but without them i'm not as sure how to apply the CSS to them as the image wants (not just black/white). Thanks again!

Comment: There are no cells in my answer at all, that's the point. But, if you are asking about the borders around the fieldsets, you would write a rule about either all fieldsets or the one you want to style.  This, for example, will change all the fieldset borders:   fieldset {border: 3px dashed red; }. I've updated my answer to show this.

Comment: To be able to style particular elements (rather than all of a type), the easiest thing to do is add an `id` attribute to that element and then the style rule would be `#theIdYouAddedToTheElement { ... }`

Comment: Ahhh ok thank you. This may be another stupid question, but when i put in the rest of the middle column data ( cheese, sauces, and special instructions) it moved them to the 3rd column and pushed the toppings off the page? would you be able to provide one last solution as how to finish that middle column with the data? I am not sure why i am having such great difficulty with this when it seems simple. Greatly appreciate the help though.

Comment: Your problem was with the last `<textarea>` element, you wrote it as: `<textarea />` when it needs a closing tag and should have been `<textarea></textarea>`. This is most-likely why your table wasn't showing the 3rd column in the first place. i don't know where you are learning your HTML from, but it looks like a source that still uses outdated syntax from 1998.

Comment: I hope this has helped and, if so, please up vote my answer and mark it as the answer.  Good luck!

Comment: I have updated my answer to show those extra fieldsets in the second column.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to the lab to work on it now and hopefully complete it. I will post my updated html/css file later on today with any other issues i run into (hopefully none) as it's due at midnight :). Thanks again Scott Marcus!

Comment: ohhh one last thing, When i go to upload the image underneath the toppings, where would the image be placed within the code?

Comment: It would simply go inside a new fieldset (without a legend so you get a continuous border around the whole thing with no text) and that fieldset would go just after the end of the toppings fieldset.

Comment: Running into another problem. When i input the 1st column with the phone number, it won't align center.

Comment: <body>
 
  <form method='post' name='onlineOrder' id='onlineOrder' action='https://zenit.senecac.on.ca/~emile.ohan/cgi-bin/echo-p.pl'
 
 <div id="wrapper">

      <div id="col1">
      <h4><u> Lab 04 </u></h4>
   <p>
   Papa's 
   Pizza
   </p>
   
   <p>
   416 or 905
   222-2626
   </p>
   
      </div>

Comment: @bp131313 Up voting and marking as the answer are two different things. You may not be able to do one of them yet, but I believe you can do the other.

Comment: I have uploaded my code above just now. Everything seems to be working fine except for a couple minor problems. The text area where (name, dob, phone, etc) are input are not alligned properly, and the image does not scale with the rest of the page.... i am unsure of how to make it fit properly as the desired image has it. Thanks!